# How to add functionality to the Admin login view?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I hope someone can help me with this.

Scenario:

1) A user goes to our website `/customer-area/` and gets logged in using the following Django code:

```
account = authenticate(email=email, password=password)
login(request, account)
```

2) Angular then sets a cookie to say she is logged in.

3) She then goes to `/admin/` and is presented with the message:

```
 You are authenticated as user@user.com, but are not authorized to access this page. Would you like to login to a different account?
```

She chooses to log in as an administrator.

4) She then goes back to `/customer-area/`.

Problem:

Angular checks a cookie to make sure she's authenticated but gets confused. The cookie says she's authenticated using the account she used in step (1) above, but Django thinks she's authenticated using the account she used in step (3) above. (Django is correct). This is causing all sorts of confusion for Angular.

So I guess I need to add some functionality to the login view to destroy the Angular cookie when an admin logs in.

Do any of you know how I can override the Admin login view?

Or perhaps there is an easier way to deal with this problem which I cannot think of.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Why are you making them login to a separate account to use admin?

Comment: Basically some staff we have will use their own customer account for the main website. But then later they'll log into the admin area using their staff account... So it's not a big issues and it doesn't happen that often, but it's something people complain about so I need to fix it...